# What kind of data is stored in the ext4 file system's journal?

Tags: filesystems, security, hard-disk

The `ext4` file system has a feature called `has_journal`. In the `dumpe2fs` output, we can see something like this:

```
# dumpe2fs /dev/sda2 | grep -i journal
Journal inode:            8
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Journal features:         journal_incompat_revoke
Journal size:             32M
Journal length:           8192
Journal sequence:         0x00000662
Journal start:            1
```

So the journal is 32M in size, and it starts at the beginning of the file system. I know that the size of the journal depends on the size of the partition. I don't remember the limits right now, but it's not that big value. So what kind of data is stored in the journal?

I've read once that if you want to secure remove a file from your disk (via `shred`), you have to take into account the file system's journal because it can store some information about the removed file. Is there a way to check what is in the journal? Are there any tools that can show the information?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The exact contents of the journal depend on how you have configured your ext4 file system. The [official ext4 documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt) says:

> There are 3 different data modes:
>
> - writeback mode
>     In data=writeback mode, ext4 does not journal data at all.  This mode provides
>     a similar level of journaling as that of XFS, JFS, and ReiserFS in its default
>     mode - metadata journaling.  A crash+recovery can cause incorrect data to
>     appear in files which were written shortly before the crash.  This mode will
>     typically provide the best ext4 performance.
> - ordered mode
>     In data=ordered mode, ext4 only officially journals metadata, but it logically
>     groups metadata information related to data changes with the data blocks into a
>     single unit called a transaction.  When it's time to write the new metadata
>     out to disk, the associated data blocks are written first.  In general,
>     this mode performs slightly slower than writeback but significantly faster than journal mode.
> - journal mode
>     data=journal mode provides full data and metadata journaling.  All new data is
>     written to the journal first, and then to its final location.
>     In the event of a crash, the journal can be replayed, bringing both data and
>     metadata into a consistent state.  This mode is the slowest except when data
>     needs to be read from and written to disk at the same time where it
>     outperforms all others modes.  Enabling this mode will disable delayed
>     allocation and O_DIRECT support.

So you can have both metadata (e.g. file name) and actual data (i.e. file contents) residing in your journal file.

If you're interested in details on the format in which transaction data is actually stored in the journal, you should refer to the respective header file:

http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/jbd2.h

There's also a wiki page which explains how these structures are laid out on the disk:

https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout

There's a packet in debian called `sleuthkit`, in which you have some tools like `jls` or `jcat`. The `jls` tool can list all journal entries of an `ext4` file system, for example:

```
# jls grafi.img

JBlk    Description
0:      Superblock (seq: 0)
sb version: 4
sb version: 4
sb feature_compat flags 0x00000000
sb feature_incompat flags 0x00000000
sb feature_ro_incompat flags 0x00000000
1:      Allocated Descriptor Block (seq: 2)
2:      Allocated FS Block 161
3:      Allocated Commit Block (seq: 2, sec: 1448889478.49360128)
4:      Allocated Descriptor Block (seq: 3)
5:      Allocated FS Block 161
6:      Allocated Commit Block (seq: 3, sec: 1448889494.3355841024)
7:      Allocated Descriptor Block (seq: 4)
8:      Allocated FS Block 145
9:      Allocated FS Block 1
10:     Allocated FS Block 161
11:     Allocated FS Block 129
12:     Allocated FS Block 8359
13:     Allocated FS Block 8353
14:     Allocated FS Block 0
15:     Allocated FS Block 130
16:     Allocated Commit Block (seq: 4, sec: 1448889528.3540304896)
...
```

And of course, there's more entries depending on the size of the journal. In this case there was about 16382, most of which were empty. If you want to do something with the log, for instance, recover some file, you have to use `jcat` in order to extract the i-node block:

```
jcat grafi.img 8 10 > blok-161
```

And inspect the single i-node. The block is `4096` bytes in size, and covers `16` i-nodes, each of which is `256` bytes long. Anyways in that way you can get the first block of an extent, the number of blocks in the extent, how many extents were used to describe that particular file, its size and other stuff like this. All you need to recover that file from the disk based only on the i-node entry that you got from the journal.

There's also `debugfs` in `e2fsprogs` package. It has `logdump` tool, which is similar to the `jls`.

Comment: So the information depends on the `/etc/fstab` configuration. In the case of the default one, only the metadata should be logged in the journal. The question is now, how to determine what's in there? How to check, for instance, the names of the files in the log? I give you +1, but I have to extract the information.

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov Sorry, such a detailed answer would require more time than I currently have. You'll have to parse the journal superblock to find where the journal data actually starts (`s_first` field, offset 0x14), then go through journal blocks identifying those with file metadata, extract inode numbers from these and do a `find /path/to/mountpoint -inum <inode number>` to actually find the name in the directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to refer the definition of the journaling file system (from wikipedia) and hopefully you will get the answer:

> A journaling file system is a file system that keeps track of changes
>   not yet committed to the file system's main part by recording the
>   intentions of such changes in a data structure known as a "journal",
>   which is usually a circular log. In the event of a system crash or
>   power failure, such file systems can be brought back online quicker
>   with lower likelihood of becoming corrupted

Refer to:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4#Features
and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system#Logical_journals

For more informatio.

Comment: I need a little bit different info in this case.